# chef solo not running in redhat linux

Tags: ruby, linux, chef-infra, chef-solo

I have installed the ChefDK rpm package in Redhat Linux 7.2.

The `chef-solo --version` command provides the correct version (`Chef: 12.19.36`).

Now I'm trying to run my recipe using the following chef-solo command:

```
chef-solo --override-runlist "recipe[demo_cookbook::default]"
```

But I am getting the following error message:

```
"Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for <my server name>"
Unknown Server Error:
---------------------
The server had a fatal error attempting to load the node data.
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:57:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:57:in `<main>'

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux

Exception raised! #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/chef/nodes>
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36/lib/chef/chef_fs/file_system/repository/chef_repository_file_system_root_dir.rb:113:in `mkdir'
```

Could you please suggest what I could do now?

Comment: He complains about a missing directory entry.  Do you have a `/var/chef/nodes` in your file system?

Comment: I don't have /var/chef/nodes. But do we need to create? Between I'm using chef solo

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Are you running as root?

Answer (score 0):

Finally it's worked for me. Forget to create a solo.rb file.

Created solo.rb file under /etc/chef directory and added the entry for the node name

node_name '10.1.10.1'